Web интерфейс на Python
Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека на Python для создания веб интерфейса? Чтобы не мучаться с HTML, JavaScript и т. д, а работать примерно как с Tkinter.
Я хочу сделать кроссплатформенное приложение на Python с интерфейсом в браузере. Из ПО желательно чтоб было нужно только сам Python и модули к нему.
Интерфейс надо наподобие диалоговых окон в Automate: Choice, Input, Confirm и Message

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

А что именно требуется то от интерфейса? Интерфейсы разные бывают. Под разные типы задач. Но вообще ничего не мешает использовать для интерфейса какую-то продвинутую JS библиотеку, а на Питоне сделать только бэкэнд.

@CrazyElf я добавил в вопрос ссылки

вообще у меня есть куча скриптов как раз на этом Automate. но всё это работает не всегда стабильно. да и только на Android с кучей костылей. поэтому я хочу переписать на Python. ну то, что может работать только на Android, я оставлю в Automate

ну а на Python можно сделать всё по красоте. на ПК для запуска просто ярлык. на Android пока ярлык через Automate и плагин для Termux

Я думаю вам подойдут:

Panel
Dash
Streamlit


Ну это если данные и дашборды, наверное. А что там автору вопроса нужно, какого типа интерфейс - непонятно.

@CrazyElf Streamlit не обязательно для отображения данных или дашбордов. Теоретически очень многие графические приложения (или веб-приложения) можно сразу на нем делать (как минимум - прототипы). По поводу dash точно не знаю, не пользовался.

@CrazyElf в обоих библиотеках помимо дашбордных вьюх, есть различные контролы и лэйаут менеджеры, достаточно для построения любого среднего приложения, если прям какие-то сильные фичи нужны будут, то тут Фласк

А, ну хорошо. Я просто сталкивался с этими двумя только в разрезе Data Science. Если там более широкое использование, то и хорошо. )

Ещё есть eel, но я с ней не работал и не знаю, насколько она хороша.
https://github.com/python-eel/Eel
https://habr.com/ru/articles/550426/
